# How to punctuate a phrase that has words between the possessor and possession?

Tags: punctuation, possessives, hyphenation

Example: the security policy for Acme Group owned and operated computers...

Obviously I could just reword it as "the security policy for computers owned and operated by Acme Group...," but if I wanted to word it like the example would there be hyphens, and if so, where?

Comment: _Acme Group-owned-and-operated computers_, maybe.

Comment: Hi Jon. Welcome to EL&U! Why do you think it's possible? Your rewording is fine. To be grammatically correct we often have to re-order the words.

Answer (score 1):

Like this:

> the security policy for Acme Group-owned and -operated computers...

Discussion:

- "Acme Group" is a proper noun and thus is not hyphenated if the original is not hyphenated.
- Note that "operated" gets a hyphen but the space after the "and" remains. This is because in the short list of two (owned and operated), the second "Acme Group" is implied.

I thought there was a reference to this guidance in Strunk & White's *Elements of Style*, but I guess not.